# How to read contents of a bin file until there is no data left

Tags: c, file, fread

I have to read a binary (.bin) file. This file has video data that is the RGBA data. Each component is compose of 4096 bytes and are of type **unsigned char**. Hence i open the file and read the file as shown below code snippet:

```
FILE *fp=fopen(path,"rb");
//Allocating memory to copy RGBA colour components
unsigned char *r=(unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*4096);
unsigned char *g=(unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*4096);
unsigned char *b=(unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*4096);
unsigned char *b=(unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*4096);

//copying file contents
fread(r,sizeof(unsigned char),4096,fp);
fread(g,sizeof(unsigned char),4096,fp);
fread(b,sizeof(unsigned char),4096,fp);
fread(a,sizeof(unsigned char),4096,fp);
```

Once the data is copied in r,g,b,a they are sent for suitable function for displaying.
The above code works fine for copying one set of RGBA data. However i should keep copying and keep sending the data for display.

I searched and could only find example of displaying contents of a file, however it is suitable only for text files i.e. the EOF technique.

Hence i kindly request the users to provide suitable suggestions for inserting the above code snippet into a loop(the loop condition).

Comment: We need some more details. Do you have to re-open the same file, and display its update contents, or or do you have a set of files that you need to open and display in sequence (ie: to generate a video)? If so, what is the naming convention/pattern for these files? Or is it that the file contains `n` sets of RGBA data, so the size of the file is `n * (4 * 4096)`?

Comment: No its one single file that is opened only once and once the file is open, in a loop we need to keep reading(fread) the rgba data and displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that an EOF technique would do just fine here, something like:

```
while (!feof(fp))
   fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), N, fp);
```

in your file do you have (R,G,B,A) values?

```
int next_r = 0;
int next_g = 0;
int next_b = 0;
int next_a = 0;
#define N 4096

while (!feof(fp))
{
    int howmany = fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), N, fp);

    for (int i=0; i<howmany; i+=4)
    {
        r[next_r++] = buffer[i];
        g[next_g++] = buffer[i+1];
        b[next_b++] = buffer[i+2];
        a[next_a++] = buffer[i+3];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All i needed is the while(!feof(fp)) condition. The rest i can easily proceed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

fread has a return value. You want to check it in case of an error.

> fread()  and  fwrite()  return the number of items successfully read or written (i.e., not the number of characters).
>          If an error occurs, or the end-of-file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).

So, you want to try to do an fread, but be sure to look for an error.

```
while (!feof(fp) {
  int res = fread(r,sizeof(unsigned char),4096,fp);
  if (res != 4096) {
     int file_error = ferror(fp)
     if (0 != file_error) {
        clearerr(fp)
        //alert/log/do something with file_error?
          break;
     }
  }
 //putting the above into a function that takes a fp 
 // and a pointer to r,g,b, or a would clean this up. 
 // you'll want to wrap each read
  fread(g,sizeof(unsigned char),4096,fp);
  fread(b,sizeof(unsigned char),4096,fp);
  fread(a,sizeof(unsigned char),4096,fp);
}
```